# Serial communication between raspberry pi3 and arduino

Tags: python-2.7, audio, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need to transfer the data from raspberry pi3 to arduino on a per minute basis. I tried it with pyserial but nothing happened. I used port name = "/Dev/ttyS0". Baud rate =9600. Can anyone help me in this with some examples.